# Check for format X-3

Tags: preg-match

Can anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong.

I am trying to check for the start of the string to be 1+ alpha chars followed by a dash and then 1+ numbers

So `x-2` `X-2` `XX-2` `XX-22` `xx-22` `Xx-2` any of these would pass. It must contain a dash preceded by letters and followed by numbers...

It would also have to pass `Xx-2x` but NOT `Xx-x3` or `3x-33`

There will NEVER be a number in front of the dash or a letter as the first character just after the dash.

This is what I have but doesn't seem to work

```
preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]+[-])+[0-9]+$/',$str)
```

Comment: It works fine for me. How are you using it?

Comment: elseif (preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]+[-])+[0-9]+$/',$_POST['aaa'])){ 
echo "Error: aaa.";
}else{

Comment: Please, edit your question and add this piece of code. Add also a var_dump of $_POST['aaa'].

Comment: Ok im an idiot... I was leaving out the exclamation mark and thus everything incorrect was passing...and everything correct was an error..   !preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]+[-])+[0-9]+$/',$str), need more coffee..

Comment: Don't worry it's happened to everybody someday ;-)